# MySql Connection Issue in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have facing mysql connection issue in laravel framework. I have added the corrent database details in env file but everytime when I run my application shows this error:

*PDOException in Connector.php line 101:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113*

Well I have create the new file to check the database connection and its working fine and also connect the database also remotely.

Comment: Check your database version and see if it matches the minimum required by Laravel.

Comment: Check value of port and host if correct

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

into

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

in your .ENV file

Answer (score 0):

change the following in your .env file and please re verify your username and password have set correctly hope your issue will resolve

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
```